# How to use componentWillUpdate in functional component by react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-lifecycle-hooks

How to use componentWillUpdate in functional component  by react hooks ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create the same effect of **componentWillUpdate**  using the combination of refs and effect hooks.

[Docs says](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate.) **componentWillUpdate**,is called every time when update,occurs.It is not called on initial render.

Now using **[useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)** hook,the returend object is persited in the complete life time of the application.

```js
const isFirstRender = React.useRef(true);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirstRender.current) {
      isFirstRender.current = false;
      return;
    }
  /*business logic for component did update*/
      
  });
```

Comment: but here still it runs after the render. not before it.

Comment: @hasan you are right, the above solution is for the componentDidUpdate.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve similar behaviour using `useLayoutEffect` which will run first before all your `useEffects`* and before rendering your elements on screen. Therefore, if you have used `useLayoutEffect` on for example animations to prepare "visual" before rendering it to the user (which was the primary use of it) it should do the trick.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
// do some modifications before rendering my component
}, [props])
```

*This is because useLayoutEffect is fired synchronously after DOM is mutated and before the browser paints the new changes.

Answer (score -1):

```
// similar to componentWillUpdate
useMemo(()=>{
    doSomething() 
}, [dep1, dep2])
```

Comment: `useMemo` is used for 1. `Memoizing result` of super slow function for same inputs 2. `Solving Referential equality problems` in dependencies re-triggering. Besides the memoization it acts the same way UseEffect does which would be `componentDidMount` / `componentDidUpdate` but not `Will`